# WR841HP v1 Like AP, not routing from LAN Ethernet ports, but routing from WIFI

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I was updating my **WR841HP v1** to **3.15.2 Build 150519 Rel.64477n**, and the procedure says "Default Settings" to take effects.

Previously my router was working like Access Point, the WAN port unplogged.

My Router from my ISP has **192.168.0.1** my WR841HP has 192.168.0.66.

When wireless devices are connected they are allow to access to internet perfectly.

But, When I connect another PC to another LAN port the router doesn't know how reach Internet. (previously to update was working)

Suppose:

```
WR841HP v1         ->   Router ISP   ->  INTERNET  ->  Google
|-LAN1:192.168.0.66     192.168.0.1                    8.8.8.8
|-WAN: Unplogged!
|
|-LAN2  ->  PC1: 192.168.0.14
|           ping to 192.168.0.1 has reply all (no loss packects).
|           ping to 8.8.8.8 (Reply from 192.168.0.66 destination net unreacheable)
|
|-WIFI  -> Android: 192.168.0.23 (youtube, google works perfectly)
```

Testing from the **TL-WR841HP** using **Diagnostic Tools** I have:

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 64 bytes of data:

 Request timed out.
 Request timed out.
 Request timed out.
 Request timed out.

 Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8
  Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Now testing to my ISP Router IP

```
Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 64 bytes of data:

 Reply from 192.168.0.1:  bytes=64  time=1  TTL=64  seq=1
 Reply from 192.168.0.1:  bytes=64  time=1  TTL=64  seq=2
 Reply from 192.168.0.1:  bytes=64  time=1  TTL=64  seq=3
 Reply from 192.168.0.1:  bytes=64  time=1  TTL=64  seq=4

 Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1
  Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
 Approximate round trip times in milliseconds:
  Minimum = 1, Maximum = 1, Average = 1
```